# how can i put an add button where a user can add his choice in a select list in html

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<label  for="Course"> Course </label>
<select name="course" >
<option>select your course`</option> 
<?php

$query="SELECT Course_Name FROM courses";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
if($result)
{
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $Course_Name=$row["Course_Name"];

        echo "<option value='".$Course_Name."'>".$Course_Name." </option>";

    }
}

?>
</select>
```

Comment: Please dont post only code, ask a question. And please use the formating tool to mark code as code.

Comment: Add his choice where? You need to properly explain what you want to do. You should also include any attempts you've made, explain what happens when you run that code and what the expected result should be. You're question is way too unspecific for us to be able to help.

Comment: I want the user of my system to add a course in case his or her course is not in the database.I have some courses in the systems' database and in case the user finds his course missing,he should be able to add it

Answer (score 0):

```
<label  for="Course"> Course </label>
<select name="course" onchange="if(this.value==-1){addop(this)}" >
   <option>select your course</option>
   <?php
      $query="SELECT Course_Name FROM courses";
      $result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
      if($result)
      {
          while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
              $Course_Name=$row["Course_Name"];

              echo "<option value='".$Course_Name."'>".$Course_Name." </option>";

          }
      }

      ?>
   <option value="-1">Add Another</option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function addop(r)
   {
    var c = window.prompt("Add Custom Course");
    if(c!=null && c!= -1)
    {
        var str = '<option value="'+c+'">'+c+'</option>';
        r.innerHTML += str;
        r.value = c;
    }

   }
</script>
```

Comment: A good answer includes a proper explanation of the code. Why/how is this the solution? What does it do and why?

Comment: thanks this worked a bit,however the 'add another' option should be pushed down to be the  last option even after adding a course...This is not happening in this case because i'm seeing it adopting the first option even after adding a course below it.....Please help in that case

Comment: And again the added course should be saved in the database too

Comment: Do you want to add it to the database after form submission or on adding the course ?